# eventRender not rendering nor displaying events on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

Good day, i'm using fullcalendar plugin to show events on my calendar. right now i'm having a problem on displaying the events in my calendar. i am using json result to get the data that will show on my calendar..

here's my code

Controller:

```
[DontWrapResult]
public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents(string start, string end)
{
    var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
    var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end);

    var result = _utils.GetEventsCalendar("ALL", fromDate, toDate);
    var eventList = from item in result
        select new
        {
            id = item.CalendarId.ToString(),
            title = item.Title,
            description = item.Description,
            start = item.FromDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("s"),
            end = item.EndDate.HasValue ? item.EndDate.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("s") : item.FromDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("s"),
            NoofGuests = item.NoofGuests,
            allDay = item.AllDay,
            type = item.CalType,
            requestedBy = item.RequestedBy,
            driverName = item.DriverName,
            providerName = item.ProviderName,
            phoneNo = item.PhoneNo,
            controlNumber = item.ControlNumber,
            status =item.StatusId
        };
    var rows = eventList.ToArray();
    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then in my javascript:

```
     var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    events: '@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents/")',
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        if (event.start <date && event.end <date) {
            element.css('background-color', '#ed5565');
            element.css('border', '1px solid #ed5565');
        } else if (event.start <=date && event.end >= date) {
            element.css('background-color', '#f8ac59');
            element.css('border', '1px solid #f8ac59');
        }
        if (event.status == 1) {
            element.css('background-color', '#0000FF');
            element.css('border', '1px solid #0000FF');
        } else if (event.status == 4)
        {
            element.css('background-color', '#00CC33');
            element.css('border', '1px solid #00CC33');
        }
        element.click(function () {
            if (event.type == 'Event') {
                $('#forBook').hide();
                $('#permitdetails').hide();
                $('#delPer').show();
                var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Events")?id=' + event.id;
            }
            else if (event.type == 'ApproveBook') {
                $('#forBook').show();
                $('#permitdetails').hide();
                $('#delPer').show();
                $("#NoofGuests").html(event.NoofGuests);
            }
            else {
                $('#forBook').hide();
                $('#permitdetails').hide();
                $('#delPer').show();
                var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Announcements")?id=' + event.id;
            }

            if (event.type == 'DeliveryPermit') {
                $('#delPer').hide();
                $('#permitdetails').show();
                $("#controlNo").html(event.controlNumber);
                $("#requestby").html(event.requestedBy);
                $("#deliverydate").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do'));
                $("#contractor").html(event.providerName);
                $("#contact").html(event.phoneNo);
                $("#drivername").html(event.driverName);
                if (event.status == 1) { $("#status").html("Arrived"); }
                else if (event.status == 4) { $("#status").html("Completed"); }
                else { $("#status").html("Submitted"); }

                //getDetails(event.id);

                var urls = '@Url.Action("Calendarpermit", "AdminHome")?id=' + event.id + '&strHide=' + "strHide";
                var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "DeliveryPermits",new { area = "Permit" })/' + event.id
                $.ajax({
                    url: urls,
                    cache: false,
                    data: {id : event.id},
                    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data){
                        $('#permitItem').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            if (event.type == 'Announcement') {
                $('#forBook').hide();
                $('#permitdetails').hide();
                $('#delPer').show();
                $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do '));
                $("#endTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do'));
            } else {
                $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
                $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
            }
            $("#eventInfo").html(event.description);

            $("#eventLink").attr('href', url);
            $("#eventContent").dialog({
                modal: true, title: event.title, width: 350
            });
        });
    }
});
```

i tried to put an alert inside the eventRender but it didn't pass or show data in my calendar.. what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors on console in F12 dev tools in browser?

Comment: check your console for errors. Check your JSON so see that the events are rendered as you expect, and that there are some events which actually match the date range being displayed on the calendar. Also `if (event.start <date` - in this snippet, what is "date" and where is it defined?

Comment: there is no error on my console.. im getting the objects when i tried console.log()

Comment: @ADyson i declare the date as date time now ( var date = new Date();).. i check my jsonResult and its getting the result  that i want but when i got on the script in  eventRender its not rendering..,  im using mvc5 vs2015 abp.zero

Comment: 1. can you put `console.log("here");` at the start of the eventRender method and check it is definitely executing? 2. Are the events that are returned from the server definitely going to render - i.e. do they cover dates that will be in the view when the calendar loads? Or if not, do they render once you change the date in fullCalendar to where the events will appear?